# How to create Custom Authorization SPI in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have multiple applications and all are authenticated with Keycloak SSO, but i need to change the authorization logic as we are using user-company-role access against application resources.I want to implement custom SPI for authorization, i need to authorize a user based on company-user-role permission.
How do implement custom authorization SPI?

Thanks,
Abees Muhammad

Comment: did you ever find an answer? trying the same now.